# Batch file to automate STM32 flashing

Tags: batch-file, stm32, firmware

In order to flash using ST-Link Utility, I wrote the following command which works:

```
"C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-Link Utility\ST-Link_CLI.exe" -c SN=XXXXXXXXXXXXX SWD UR FREQ=400 -P "C:\flash STM32\test.hex" -V -HardRst
```

I would like to automate this by getting the serial number using the `ST-Link_CLI.exe` commands and the `.hex` file in the folder where the batch file sits, so that I can just click this `.bat` file to flash using any debugger (SN) that is connected.

I can get the serial number using this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "output_cnt=0"
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('"C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe" -List') do (
    set /a output_cnt+=1
    set "output[!output_cnt!]=%%f"
)
for /L %%a in (1 1 !output_cnt!) do call echo !output[%%a]!
pause
set "str=SN"
for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) do (
    echo !output[%%n]!|find "SN" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found at!output[%%n]!)
)
pause
```

`!output[%%a]!` is `"   SN:XXXXXXXXXXX"` when the line in the `output_cnt` contains the string `SN`

I am a complete novice when it comes to writing effective batch scripts and was wondering if anyone could help me automate this task.

Updated code:

```
set "STfilepath=C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe"
set "output_cnt=0"
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('"!STfilepath!" -List') do (
    set /a output_cnt+=1
    set "output[!output_cnt!]=%%f"
)
::iterate thru output array to find SN and parse it to get the serial number
set "serial=NONE"
for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) do (
    echo !output[%%n]!
    FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%1 in ("!output[%%n]!") do (
        if "%%1" == "SN" (
            set "serial=%%2"
        )
    )
)
echo serial number is !serial!
set "hexfile=NONE"
for /r %%i in (*.hex) do (set "hexfile=%%i")
echo hexfile is !hexfile!
set "CMD="!STfilepath!" -c SN=!serial! SWD UR FREQ=400 -P "!hexfile!" -V -HardRst"
echo %CMD%
%CMD%
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string with a `FOR /F` loop.

```
...
set "serial=NONE"
for /L %%n in (1 1 !output_cnt!) do (
    echo !output[%%n]!
    FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%1 in ("!output[%%n]!") do (
        if "%%1" == "SN" (
            set "serial=%%2"
        )
    )
)
echo Found serial: !serial!
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much jeb.